# SourceDataLine buffersize resulting in clicks and stops in playback

Tags: java, audio, buffer, javax.sound.sampled

I am trying to play back audio I create in realtime in my application with a `SourceDataLine`. When opening the `SourceDataLine` with `sdl.open(format)`, it creates a default buffer of 32000 (my sample rate), so effectively one second. But since my application should be low-latency, I have tried to use a smaller buffer. (`sdl.open(format, buffer);`)

On generating sound, I use a buffer of 512 sampels at the moment (haven't figured out the best value there, if you have any insight, I would appreciate it)

Some pseudocode for my algorithm:

```
int pos = 0;
int max = 512;
byte sampleBuffer[] = new byte[max];
while(active) {
    sampleBuffer[pos++] = generateSample(); // actually I generate doubles and make bytes out of em later, but who cares
    if (pos == max) {
        sdl.write(sampleBuffer, 0, pos);
        pos = 0;
    }
}
```

When I try to use my own buffer size (I tried everything from `max` to `max * 2 // * 4; * 8; * 16`), I get a lot of clicks and noise.

If you guys have any insight on the right way to go here, I would really appreciate it. I don't know how much bigger my SourceDataLine buffer should be than the chunks that I write to the Line, if at all. Are there any tricks to getting this smooth? I am quite certain that my program generates the audio fast enough, so that should not be the problem.

Comment: generateSample() is the key here; if it generates garbage, someone cares!

Comment: It isn't .... I temporarily had the buffer written to a WAV file, and the generated file was completely fine. It's really not the samples, it is definitely the buffer of the sourcedataline. I just don't know how to get it to not click